# ClassCastException[null] when grouping on a particular field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to group the results on a particular field by using the following query:

```
{ 
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 0, 
  "fields": [ 
    "exitPage.categoryId" 
  ], 
  "aggs": { 
    "check": { 
      "terms": { 
        "field": "exitPage.categoryId" 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Elasticsearch server throws this exception:

```
{ 
  "error": "ClassCastException[null]", 
  "status": 500 
}
```

and that too, on an intermittent basis - sometimes it returns results while sometimes it does not. There is no more descriptive information available in the server log.

Does anyone have a clue to this problem?

Edit: Added error log as asked by [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val)

```
[2016-02-01 12:42:28,773][DEBUG][action.search.type ] [elastic71] failed to reduce search
org.elasticsearch.action.search.ReduceSearchPhaseException: Failed to execute phase [fetch], [reduce]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction$2.onFailure(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:159)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:41)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Comment: Do all your documents have a value for that field or can that field be null sometimes?

Comment: And do all you documents have an `exitPage` object? Apparently, some might not.

Comment: Yes, some might not have this `exitPage` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the instance restarted and this fixed the issue.

I assume that it was some corrupt cache / index internally which got cleaned up once the instance was restarted. If someone knows a better explanation, do edit this post.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that exception because some of your documents don't have an `exitPage` property and hence the aggregator cannot get the `categoryId` value for those documents.

What you need to do in order to prevent this, is to filter out the documents that don't have an `exitPage` property, for instance by using an [`exists`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {                        <--- add this query
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "exitPage"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "check": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "exitPage.categoryId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not work... Three states - 
1) Result, 
2) {
"error": "ReduceSearchPhaseException[Failed to execute phase [fetch], [reduce] ]; nested: ClassCastException; ",
"status": 503
}
3) {
"error": "ClassCastException[null]",
"status": 500
}

Comment: There must be something logged in your ES logs. Can you share that (in your question maybe so you can paste the full output)?